# Secure an API if needed

Tags: android, ios, api, security, mobile

So I have built an ios&android app that lists a set of books.
When you open the app in lists the books, no account needed.

Now the API is located at `example.com/api/list_books?page=1&per_page=10` and this API lists the books returns a JSON array.

Right now anyone can access this URL and get the data which I think it's fine since the data is anyways listed on a blog as posts.

**My question is if it's worth to secure the API and how?**

If I use something like JWT, I think that's kinda pointless, because If I do a request to `api/auth` to get the token, I think anyone at home can see through their router what data is sending to the API, user and password, because it will be the same for everyone since you just open the app and the books are listed.

**Is it worth to do anything here since this is not private user data? If yes what solutions do you propose?**

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I don't really see any option to really secure it if it's public. If you're worried about abuse you can always rate limit your api by ip address.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to answer the question of whether you think there is, or could be, value in the data you have in your API.

If there is and you don't want someone to steal the data, you can do a bunch of things to protect it. Nothing is perfect, and the more secure you want your data to be the more effort you need to put in.

The first step is to use HTTPS if you aren't already. That helps prevent people from intercepting the traffic en route.

After that your primary problem is that you don't know what is being used to access your API. It might not be your software and could just as easily be a script or someone else's app. There are a bunch of different things that you can do to increase your confidence that only authorised things are accessing your API. The most common approach is probably to embed an API key in your app. You can use this key to identify your app as an authorized one.

Only requests that contain some data that is signed by the secret key are allowed to retrieve data from the API. You can't just send the key because someone could just MITM the traffic(even with https) and steal it really easily.

The next problem is that someone could get your app and reverse engineer it to extract the secret. To make that more difficult you can obfuscate your code, but you are still giving the key away in the app and if someone is super determined they can probably still get at it.

There is more you can do, I work for a company that has a commercial solution that tries to address this use case, but it's really a question of how valuable the data is and how much effort you think is reasonable to try and protect it.